# How to change the length of a value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of one column:

```
    close
0   176.380
1   176.290
2   176.740
3   177.200
4   177.600
5   177.270
6   177.190
7   177.660
8   177.890
9   177.450
10  177.185
```

The values (type = float) in this column differ in length. I want to have all values have the same length (6). But how do I do this?

I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 

conn = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
rawdata_set = pd.read_sql('SELECT close FROM tbl_data', conn)

training_set = rawdata_set.head(100) 
for valid in training_set:
    count = 0
    if len(str(valid)) == 7:
        valid = int(str(training_set)[:6])
        count += 1
```

The expected result is that the length of the values would all be 6 long but the results is that I don't see anything change. Perhaps I'm making this more complicated than it should be.

```
    close
0   176.38
1   176.29
2   176.74
3   177.20
4   177.60
5   177.27
6   177.19
7   177.66
8   177.89
9   177.45
10  177.18
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and preferred output?

Comment: If they are all different lengths, why do you need `valid` to be exactly 7? I'm referring to your line: `if len(str(valid)) == 7:`. If you want to have ALL the values the same length, why restrict the search to a length of 7?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the particular float column into a column of strings using the `apply` method and string formatting.

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

s
Out[6]: 
0    0.087582
1    0.896488
2    0.560789
3    0.298119
4    0.612291
5    0.750120
6    0.009479
7    0.449085
8    0.497474
9    0.342821

s.apply('{:.2f}'.format)

Out[9]: 
0    0.09
1    0.90
2    0.56
3    0.30
4    0.61
5    0.75
6    0.01
7    0.45
8    0.50
9    0.34
dtype: object
```

Comment: `.6f` in this case

Comment: I think it should be `7.3f` or just `.3f` for 3 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks guys! But I do receive an error here: TypeError: ('unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__', 'occurred at index close')

Comment: If I interpret the error correctly it looks like that values in the DataFrame are not float but string.

Comment: when I do .Columns on the initial Dataframe I see he following: Index(['close'], dtype='object')

Comment: try `df['close'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)`. If not, try `df['close'].astype(float).apply('{:.2f}'.format)`

Comment: Thanks @Gerges I had the same thought:
    trainingC_set = training_set.close.astype('float')
    trainingC_set = trainingC_set.apply('{:.2f}'.format)

Yours is better btw.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to actually change the dataset, which you are not doing. `valid` is just a variable holding the same number that was in that location you are currently at:

```
training_set = rawdata_set.head(100) 
for ind, valid in enumerate(training_set):
    count = 0
    if len(str(valid)) == 7:
        training_set.iloc[ind] = float(str(training_set)[:6])
        count += 1
```

Comment: I've tried yours but I still have the same output as the input. Perhaps this might happen due that the len == 7 is the same as the str(training_set)[:7])